# Nodejs Swig Template Command Line

Tags: npm, swig-template

Cant install Twig Template CLI

http://paularmstrong.github.io/swig/docs/cli/

when i install sudo npm install swig --global

i will get

command not found error when trying to execute swig

Comment: Check if the npm global modules are on PATH. That's not a problem of swig, it's more likely a problem with npm/your os

Comment: that's what i thought but i'm not getting past it. npm global modules should already be on PATH since other modules work fine.. 
i'll check before updating as answered

Comment: worked fine on a different box.. likely PATH wasn't updated on the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running your command with `-g`?

works for me `sudo npm install swig -g`